# Vibrator hasAmplitudeControl not working properly

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

I am currently developing an application that uses vibration. However, when I use the hasAmplitudeControl() function, I found that it does not work correctly, especially with my Rog 6 phone. Rog 6 obviously has amplitude control, but hasAmplitudeControl() returns false.

Does anyone have the same problem as me, and does anyone have any better solutions to check if the device supports vibration intensity control?

Thanks all

Does anyone have the same problem as me, and does anyone have any better solutions to check if the device supports vibration intensity control?